# ROC Curve and AUC value of SVM model

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn

I am new to ML. I have a question so I am evaluating my SVM model.

Example:

```
SVM_MODEL = svm.SVC() 
SVM_MODEL.fit(X_train,y_train) 
SVM_OUTPUT = SVM_MODEL.predict(X_test)
```

And I want to plot my roc curve and AUC value for it is this the correct code?

```
fpr1, tpr1, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_valid, SVM_OUTPUT, pos_label=0)
plt.ylabel(“True Positive Rate”)
plt.xlabel(“False Positive Rate”)
plt.title(“ROC Curve”)
plt.plot(tpr1,fpr1)
plt.show()
auc = np.trapz(fpr1,tpr1)
print(‘Area Under ROC Curve:’, auc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know sklearn then you should use this.

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve
```

[Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_roc_curve.html) for you.

Regarding the AUC, it will be shown on the graph automatically.

[image: AUC curve]

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for sharing. One last question that is this how we plot roc curve plt.plot(tpr1,fpr1) ? First, we pass true positive rates and then false positive?

Comment: I gave you exactly how you plot it with an example just click on the link and read the first sentence. 
`plot_roc_curve(model,X_test,y_test)` it cant get any easier.